Python code to scrape Greyhound results from https://www.gbgb.org.uk/
I am using the GBGB site to download the full greyhound results for a certain track. I am using the Python code below to get the full result for each day. The code below downloads the full-day results from Crayford for each given day (in the example code below I am downloading the results from the 25th of May to the 2nd of June. Each day where there is a meeting in Crayford has a separate meeting and raceID for example in the code below 1st June meeting = 411583 and race id = 1042517. As you can see if I want to download, for example, 3 months of data, I have to individually specify the meeting ID and race ID in the URL as a separate line which is timeconsuming.
i was wondering is there a way I can webcrape the whole site to download say 6 months' worth of results rather than having a line-buy-line url specified. I am new to webscraping and not sure how to do this. My actual code has 9 months of data so you can imagine the size of the code as every day has to go in a separate url line.
Any help is appreciated. The site I am getting the data from is https://www.gbgb.org.uk/
import httpx
from selectolax.parser import HTMLParser
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests
from  datetime import datetime, timedelta
import ndjson

   
URLs = [
"https://api.gbgb.org.uk/api/results/meeting/411238?raceId=1040677",#25th May Sat
     "https://api.gbgb.org.uk/api/results/meeting/411239?raceId=1040615",#26th May Sun
     "https://api.gbgb.org.uk/api/results/meeting/411378?raceId=1041270",#28st May Tue
     "https://api.gbgb.org.uk/api/results/meeting/411461?raceId=1042006",#30rd May Thu
     "https://api.gbgb.org.uk/api/results/meeting/411477?raceId=1042178",#31th May Fri
    
    #June
     
     "https://api.gbgb.org.uk/api/results/meeting/411583?raceId=1042517",#01st Jun Sat
     "https://api.gbgb.org.uk/api/results/meeting/411452?raceId=1042214",#02nd Jun Sun
]

json_list = []
for url in URLs:
    resp = requests.get(url)
    page_context = resp.text
    print(page_context)
    json_file = json.loads(page_context)
    json_list.extend(json_file)
with open('C:/mypath/Grey_results.json', 'w') as f:
    ndjson.dump(json_list, f)


Are you asking if there is a pattern by which the meeting and race id:s can be predicted? Or are you asking for somebody to explore the site and see if there is a location where they can be enumerated? Neither of these seem particularly suitable for Stack Overflow.

What's ndjson?

I just want to know if there is a way to webscrape from the site instead of specifying each day by line by line , i presume there is no easy way

This isn't really "web scraping" - you're just invoking an API that returns JSON data.
There is a variation of this API that would facilitate your requirements as follows:
import requests
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from functools import partial
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import json

DFMT = "%Y-%m-%d"

def get_results(track, date):
    page = 1
    results = []
    while True:
        url = f"https://api.gbgb.org.uk/api/results?page={page}&itemsPerPage=100&date={date}&race_type=race&track={track}"
        with requests.get(url) as response:
            response.raise_for_status()
            data = response.json()
            items = data["items"]
            if len(items) == 0:
                break # no data available for the given criteria
            results.extend(items)
            meta = data["meta"]
            if meta["page"] == meta["pageCount"]:
                break # last page
            page += 1
    return results

def gendates(start, end):
    _start = datetime.strptime(start, DFMT)
    _end = datetime.strptime(end, DFMT)
    while _start <= _end:
        yield _start.strftime(DFMT)
        _start += timedelta(days=1)

def main(track, start, end):    
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as exe:
        for result in exe.map(partial(get_results, track), gendates(start, end)):
            print(json.dumps(result, indent=2))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # specify track, start and end dates here
    main("Crayford", "2024-05-25", "2024-06-02")

